# independent ftp proxy for enable ssl layer

Tags: proxy, ftp, tls, gateway, application

is there available any software for ftp proxying?
Problem is old ftp server that cannot take ssl layer.
Idea is, make additional gateway that take client connections with ssl, uncrypt this and put connection into this old ftp server.
I found FTP-Proxy, but it supports only uncrypted connections on both sided.
I found Delegate also, but it is big combo pack and is very expensive.
And the last I found http://www.ftpproxy.org/ , it is very interesting. Unfortunately it is not developed until 2011 year (not supported for 5 years:( )
Can anybody help me with looking for proper ftp bridge/gateway/forwarder ?

Comment: You might look into using the [`mod_proxy` module for ProFTPD](https://github.com/Castaglia/proftpd-mod_proxy).  Full disclaimer: I'm the author.

Comment: I'm looking for more open software, but proftpd module is a good workaround. thank you for it. But goal is some middleware what can I easly extend with mutch more protocol, including http pop smtp and much more if it has a sense.